# Is it possible to create a native library using react native?

Tags: react-native

We have native (Android and iOS) versions of an application. We want to create a new UI component using React Native which can be shared by the two applications. So essentially we would create a new View using React Native and then provide an Android and iOS interface so this view can be invoked from the native applications. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you checked [integration-with-existing-apps](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html)?

Comment: Yes, the issue with the process to integrate with existing applications is that you need to convert the native project to be a react native project. I just want to have my library project be a react native project.

Comment: What did you end up doing?